# what is :data-col attribute in div element?

Tags: html, vue.js

I found this in vue component , I didn't understand the purpose of :data-col in div , could you explain please

```
<template>
  <div
    class="vertical-layout h-100"
    :class="[layoutClasses]"
    :data-col="isNavMenuHidden ? '1-column' : null"
  >
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp#:~:text=The%20data%2D*%20attribute%20gives,server%2Dside%20database%20queries).

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of [Vue attribute binding (also known as v-bind)](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings) and [HTML data-* attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_data-.asp), along with [Tenary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

This v-bind and tenary method is a common practice in vue development, especially in conditional rendering.

The purpose of this code is to put the `data-col` attribute with a value of `1-column` on the specified div when the `isNavMenuHidden` is true

Answer (score 0):

this is a bind attribute and means that data-col is equal to 1-column when 'isNavMenuHidden' is true